# Q-learning agent stucks in an infinite loop

Tags: machine-learning, python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am simulating a mouse to find a cheese on an empty table. I randomly put a cheese on the table and let the mouse find the cheese without falling off the table. The problem is, in test part, agent goes into an infinite loop if i don't provide any epsilon values. If I provide an epsilon value, agent can fall off the table. The table is discrete but the cheese is random. So i need the mouse to learn the table first. Say the agent at 322. Agent finds the largest Q and moves to the left which is 321. This time, largest value is 322. And it keeps going...

I couldn't find any problems. Is my approach wrong or missing something?

Here's the code i have written:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

class Env:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid_size = 10 # 10x10 matrix
        self.observation_size = self.grid_size * self.grid_size
        self.action_size = 4 # 0: left 1: right 2: up 3: down

    def reset(self):
        self.grid = []
        self.holes = []
        self.target = []
        self.x = np.random.randint(0, self.grid_size)
        while True:
            self.y = np.random.randint(0, self.grid_size)
            if self.x != self.y:
                break
        self.state = (self.y * self.grid_size) + self.x
        while True:
            self.target_x = np.random.randint(0, self.grid_size)
            while True:
                self.target_y = np.random.randint(0, self.grid_size)
                if self.target_y != self.target_x:
                    break
            self.target = (self.target_y * self.grid_size) + self.target_x
            if self.target != self.state:
                break
        return self.state

    def step(self, action):
        reward = 0
        done = False
        # 0: left 1: right 2: up 3: down
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        if action == 0:
            self.x = self.x - 1
        elif action == 1:
            self.x = self.x + 1
        elif action == 2:
            self.y = self.y + 1
        elif action == 3:
            self.y = self.y - 1
        self.state = (self.y * self.grid_size) + self.x
        if self.x < 0 or self.x >= self.grid_size:
            if self.x < 0:
                reward = -100
            else:
                reward = -100
            #self.x = x
            done = True
        elif self.y < 0 or self.y >= self.grid_size:
            if self.y < 0:
                reward = -100
            else:
                reward = -100
            #self.y = y
            done = True
        elif self.state == self.target:
            reward = 100
            done = True
        else:
            reward = 1
        return self.state, reward, done

def train(env, alpha, gamma, epsilon, epoch):
    print("Training...")
    qt = np.zeros([env.observation_size * env.observation_size, env.action_size])
    error_list = []
    reward_list = []
    errors = 0
    rewards = 0
    for ep in range(epoch):
        state = env.reset()
        while True:
            if random.uniform(0, 1) < epsilon:
                action = np.random.randint(env.action_size)
            else:
                action = np.argmax(qt[state])
            next_state, reward, done = env.step(action)
            # Q function
            old_value = qt[state, action]
            next_max = np.max(qt[next_state])
            next_value = old_value + alpha * (reward + gamma * next_max - old_value)
            qt[state, action] = next_value
            state = next_state
            rewards += reward
            if reward < 0:
                errors += abs(reward)
            if done:
                break
        error_list.append(errors)
        reward_list.append(rewards)
        print("Episode: {}, Rewards: {}, Errors: {}".format(ep, rewards, errors))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    ax[0].plot(reward_list)
    ax[1].plot(error_list)
    plt.show()
    return qt

def test(env, qt, epsilon):
    print()
    print("Testing...")
    error_list = []
    reward_list = []
    rewards = 0
    errors = 0
    state = env.reset()
    steps = 0
    while True:
        steps += 1
        """
        if random.uniform(0, 1) < epsilon:
            action = np.random.randint(env.action_size)
        else:
            action = np.argmax(qt[state])
        r = np.random.randint(0, 2)
        """
        action = np.argmax(qt[state])
        next_state, reward, done = env.step(action)
        state = next_state
        rewards += reward
        print(state, action)
        if reward <= -100:
            errors += 1
        if done:
            break
    error_list.append(errors)
    reward_list.append(rewards)
    print("Steps: {}, Rewards: {}, Errors: {}".format(steps, rewards, errors))
    print("Target pos:", env.target_x, env.target_y)
    print("State:", env.x, env.y)

alpha = 0.1 # learning rate
gamma = 0.99 # discount rate
epsilon = 0.1 # explore rate
epoch = 100000 # epoch

load_file = True
fl = "./grid.pck"

env = Env()
if not load_file:
    qt = train(env, alpha, gamma, epsilon, epoch)
    with open(fl, 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(qt, fp)
else:
    with open(fl, 'rb') as fp:
        qt = pickle.load(fp)
test(env, qt, epsilon)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a-learning to stick in sub optimal loop just like your case where the best action to take in state A take you to state B and the best action in the state B takes you back into state A.
I found two solutions for this so far:

1. Keep track of the path you take and avoid returning to the same state or give negative reward if it returns to the same state. You can do it by keeping the whole path or some last parts of the path inside a list and then if an action take you to a state that is already traversed you give negative reward for taking that action.
2. Design a reward system that does not allow you to return to the previous step. This is highly dependant on your problem. For example giving positive reward for a mouse that gets closer to the goal(if an action takes the agent closer to the goal give positive reward for taking that action and otherwise give negative or zero reward) prevents the mouse agent to turn around and return to previous stage.

Comment: I like to randomly uniformly sweep individual states, not paths.  So if I'm making a policy then I run Q over the board (a few hundred times, because it is offline and slow) and let it normalize.  Intermediate steps might have loops, but epsilon-greedy gets you out of those.